# How can I BCP queryout with filename from table?

Tags: sql, bcp

I'm extracting many BLOBs to files using BCP and wonder if there's a way to give each file a unique name using an ID field from the SQL table.
This works:

```
DECLARE  @Command NVARCHAR(4000)  
SET @Command = 'bcp "SELECT FileData FROM MyDB.dbo.Attachments 
                WHERE Hist_ID = ''00004F13''" 
                queryout "C:\Wha.pdf" -T -c -C RAW -S SERVERNAME -U SA -P pa$$word'  
EXEC xp_cmdshell   @Command
```

But to get the filename, I've tried:

```
DECLARE @FileName varchar(50),  
@Command NVARCHAR(4000)  
SET @FileName = Hist_ID+'wha.PDF'  
SET @Command = 'bcp "SELECT FileData FROM MyDB.dbo.Attachments 
                WHERE Hist_ID = ''00004F13''"     queryout'  
SET @Command = @Command + 'C:\' + @FileName + '-T -c -C RAW 
                           -S SERVERNAME -U SA -P pa$$word'  
EXEC xp_cmdshell   @Command
```

I get an error:  Invalid column name 'Hist_ID'.
Is there some way to do this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: You'll need to use a cursor to go through `MyDB.dbo.Attachments` and build the SQL dynamically and execute it per row. Someone more enthusiastic than me might post this, or I will if no one else does.

Comment: Would be awesome if you could, Nick! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Hi all--  I'm desperate for a solution here. I've searched everywhere and only found "how to add datetime to your bcp filename". Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. This is the only way I know have to execute one row at a time.

This code just prints the command. Uncomment the xp_cmdshell to make it actually run. You might want to start with a small sample first (by limiting the select)

```
DECLARE @Hist_ID VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Ext VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @Command NVARCHAR(4000)  


DECLARE cAttachments CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT Hist_ID,Extension
FROM MyDB.dbo.Attachments 
ORDER BY Hist_ID

OPEN cAttachments

FETCH NEXT FROM cAttachments
INTO @Hist_ID, @Ext

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SET @Command = 'bcp "SELECT FileData FROM MyDB.dbo.Attachments 
                WHERE Hist_ID = ''' + @Hist_ID + '''"
                queryout "C:\' + @Hist_ID + '.' + @Ext + '" -T -c -C RAW -S SERVERNAME -U SA -P pa$$word'  

    PRINT @Command

    -- EXEC xp_cmdshell   @Command


    FETCH NEXT FROM cAttachments
    INTO @Hist_ID, @Ext

END

CLOSE cAttachments
DEALLOCATE cAttachments
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks Nick. This works but I have two issues:  1.  For some rows, I get this error (because the Hist_ID has alpha character):  [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0000400B' to data type int.   2.  I neglected to add that I also need to pull the file extension, which will vary, from a column in the same table. How could I add that to the file name? Thanks again.

Comment: OK I've fixed the conversion error and added a column for your extension. Try that and see.

Comment: Works perfectly! (just added @Ext to the FETCH NEXT clause)  --thanks for your help!